# Can I use a wildcard rule to prevent Yandex from indexing all tag and date URLs created by Joomla K2?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, duplicate-content, joomla

I have a site based on joomla and K2 component. I use K2 Tags and Calendar, but i have problem with pages indexing

When yandex.ru begin to index it i find out that it index my tags and SEO test sites complains about duplicate pages. And also it just index many empty url from calendar.

So i add

`Disallow: /tag/`

in `robots.txt`

But it did not help a lot, because of way K2 create URLs.

For example here latest indexed pages from yandex:

```
/программирование/date/2020/3/2&format=feed&Itemid=136&type=atom
/программирование/qt5/date/2020/2
/программирование/qt5/date/2020/3
/программирование/qt5/date/2020/3/7
/программирование/qt5/date/2020/3/7&format=feed&Itemid=137&type=rss
/программирование/qt5/tag/Меню
/программирование/qt5/tag/eltex
/программирование/qt5/tag/esr
/программирование/qt5/tag/esr200
/date/2020/2/18&format=feed&Itemid=101&type=rss
```

So it again begin index tags and calendar.

How wildcard urls like this `*/tag/*` or `/date/` to prevent this modules been indexed?